# schedule cron job for every hour is not working

Tags: cron, php, scheduling

I am running a single instance cron job for certain task. My script looks like below:

```
# every hour interval
0 * * * * php /project/yii daily/order

# every 30 minutes interval
*/30 * * * * php /project/yii daily/sample
```

I am using `https://crontab.guru/` to get the values. The scheduling works but for `order`, I set it to run every hour interval but instead it runs every five hours instead. I checked the path and script and it is correct.

I was wondering why is does not run hourly as set?

Comment: Test the scheduling separately with `0 * * * * date >> /tmp/test_x.txt`. Also "every 5 hours": does it start over at 0:00 every midnight, or does it run at 01:00 the second day (i.e. strict 5-hour intervals), which would indicate some timer other than cron.

Comment: For hourly action the format should be 0 */1 * * *

Comment: @Paul_Pedant It runs every five hours without starting over.

Comment: @elmclose  A step of /1 is the default anyway. `A field may be an asterisk, which always stands for first-last` which for hour is 0-23. If this is needed for hour, then you also need */1 for day of month.

Comment: @nativemash  So it runs at 00:00, 05:00, 10:00 .. on the first day, and 01:00, 06:00, 11:00 .. on the second day ? Cron **cannot** do that. Your `php` code contains its own timing constraints, or waits for some external event, and skips the missing cron events itself. Maybe it runs for around 4.5 hours, and refuses to allow two copies of itself to run simultaneously. Test by making the command part: `date  >> /tmp/test_x.txt && php /project/yii daily/order`. Then you can see cron log each hourly execution, and then check to see php running (or not) in `top`.

Answer (score -1):

Jobs run through `cron` aren't run in the same runtime environment that you have on your desktop. None of your `PATH` changes, or other environment  variable settings from `~/.bashrc` are automatically propagated to  your `cron` job. For example, there's no `$DISPLAY`, so GUI programs need special treatment (read `man xhost`).

One can set environment variables for all one's `cron` jobs in the `crontab` file
Read `man 5 crontab`.

Look at the results of  `echo "=== id ===";id;echo "=== set ===";set;echo "=== env ===";env | sort;echo "=== alias ===";alias` in each of your environments.

Since the `command` part of the `crontab` line is, by default,  interpreted by `/bin/sh`, which has a simpler syntax than `/bin/bash`, I recommend having `command` be a call to a `bash` script  (executable, mounted, starts with `#!/bin/bash`) which sets up the environment,  then calls the desired program.